# WordPress showing strange characters - UTF8

Tags: multisite, import

I've just changed webserver but are having some problems with the encoding of the new site.

I have exported part of my WordPress site from my old webhost and imported into my new WordPress multsite setup.

Everything looks fine from the database, but when viewing the site within WordPress it's all messed up with strange characters.

The content is in Norwegian, and contains characters like `æ, ø, å` but instead of these I now get  `Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥`

The database is set to use *utf8_general_ci*

WordPress config file is set to:

`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

`define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');`

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this doesn't show correctly when the encoding seem right as well as the database content. Only from the WordPress side the content is messed up.

I'm using HeidiSQL to import the data from the old server.

Any ideas of what wrong here?

---

**UPDATE!**

By removing the utf8 from the wp-config file like showed below, the strange characters goes away...

`define('DB_CHARSET', '');`

`define('DB_COLLATE', '');`

**BUT, is this a safe way to go?**

Answer (score 0):

When you import from HeidiSQL, make sure whn selecting the file, to change the Enconding Option below to UTF-8, revert your wp-config the way it was